# Can't change Entity Framework members to protected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following DbContext classes in my application which work fine:

```
public partial class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyAppContext : BaseContext
{
    public new IQueryable<Customer> Customers()
    {
        return base.Customers.Where(n => n.Active == true);
    }

    public new IQueryable<Contact> Contacts()
    {
        return base.Contacts.Where(n => n.Active == true);
    }
}
```

I want all calls to Customers or Contacts in my application to filter out non active records.  This approach works well but someone can accidently call Customers or Contacts on my base context, which i want to avoid.

I thought the ideal solution would be to make the members in my base context protected so that they could only be accessed by the MyAppContext, but this fails as no data is ever loaded in the 2 DbSet's. e.g.

```
public partial class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    protected virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

When i set these to protected then no data is loaded, when they are public everythig is fine (but this exposes these publically which i want to avoid).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: I think this has to do with the way EF works internally. It will try to propagate the properties from outside which violates the access modifier.

Comment: I know it works for properties on the objects, so how about making the `DbSet`s `protected internal`?

Comment: This is pseudo encapsulation. Consumers will always have access to `context.Set<T>()`. Also, this won't prevent getting inactive customers through navigation properties. Soft deletes requires a more rigorous approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to not use the `DbSet<>` properties on your base class and use instead the fluent API to declare your entity types:

```
public partial class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>();
    }
}
```

And then in `MyAppContext`, you can declare your properties this way:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> Customers =>
    Set<Customer>.Where(n => n.Active == true);
public IQueryable<Contact> Contacts =>
    Set<Contact>.Where(n => n.Active == true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an implementation for them instead of making them Auto Properties.

```
public partial class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get { return this.Set<Customer>(); } }
    protected virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get { return this.Set<Contact>(); } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use empty `DbContext` and then pass instance of it to a generic repository like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository where T : class, new()
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _set;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = _db;
        _set = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query => _set.Where(m=>m.Active == true);

    public virtual void Add(T entity) => _set.Add(entity);

    public virtual void Update(T entity) => this._context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

    public virtual void Delete(T entity) =>  _set.Remove(entity);
}
```

This pattern allows you a much fine graded control over entity operation. You can also implement different repositories with different query/update logic.